# Reverse foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

In a Sqlite database, I have a table Vector3 where I store my vectors X, Y, Z.

Vector3 Ids can be referenced by a lot of different fields in different tables.
The behavior I'm looking for, is that whenever an entry in another table referencing the Vector3 Id is deleted, the Vector3 row referenced is deleted too.

If I put a foreign key on the other tables referencing Vector3 Id, then when a Vector3 entry will be deleted the entry in the other table will be deleted.

What I want is the reverse on delete cascading behavior, but with the primary key still being the Vector3 Id.

I'm supposing this concept doesn't exist and the way I managed to formulate this question to google didn't bring up anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it does exist. You could use a trigger though to clean up the other tables on deletion of a record