# Reverse foreign key cascading (or how to collect database garbage)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, foreign-keys

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540007/reverse-foreign-key-constraint) albeit with a twist (namely, I need what basically is reference counting behavior here).

We have several tables (Foo, Bar, Baz) where the things stored in them all reference zero or more of another kind of thing (a Blah).  We sometimes make new Blahs and attach them to a Foo, a Bar, or a Baz; however, we don't edit existing Blahs as they may be pointed-to by multiple things at once.  Currently, we have a batch process that sweeps through all the Foos, Bars, and Bazes in the database, marking Blahs as used, and then deleting all unmarked Blahs, but this is quite costly, so we're looking for a way to do it online, ideally through the database itself.  We can research trigger-based approaches, but would rather treat those as a last resort.

Specifically, referring to the schema and data in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21063):

- If I insert a new Bar 'some_bar' and have it point at a new Blah with PK 'r', only the already-orphaned Blah 'x' should be deleted.
- If I delete 'a_foo', Blahs 'a' and 'x' should be the only ones that are deleted -- 'b' and 'c' in particular need to stay put
- If I delete 'another_foo', Blahs 'x' and 'y' need to be deleted
- If I delete 'a_bar', only Blah 'x' can be deleted -- Blah 'c' in particular needs to stay
- If I delete 'another_bar', again, only Blah 'x' can be deleted -- Blah 'q' needs to stick around
- If I delete 'a_baz', all of Blahs 'p', 'x', and 'z' need to be deleted
- If I delete 'another_baz', only Blah 'x' can be deleted -- Blahs 'b' and 'q' need to stay around

Am I stuck with triggers or the existing mark-sweep batch processing for this job, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for mark and sweep batch processing since the following query will do the job as long as `BLAHS.PK` can never contain a comma:

```
delete from blahs 
where not exists (select 1 from foo where ','||some_blahs||',' like '%,'||blahs.pk||',%')
  and not exists (select 1 from bar where bar.blah = blahs.pk)
  and not exists (select 1 from baz where blahs.pk in (baz.a_blah, baz.another_blah));
```

Your table `FOO` is troublesome since you can't define any referential integrity or any helpful indexes on it like you can with `BAR` and `BAZ`.

A better DB design might be to replace `FOO.SOME_BLAHS` with a many to many relation table:

```
create table foo_blahs ( foo_pk varchar2(20)  references foo on delete cascade
                       , blah_pk varchar2(20) references blahs
                       , constraint foo_blah_pk primary key (foo_pk, blah_pk) enable);
```

Then instead of:

```
insert into foo (pk, some_blahs) values ('a_foo', 'a,b,c');
```

You would use:

```
insert into foo (pk) values ('a_foo');
insert into foo_blahs (foo_pk, blah_pk) values ('a_foo', 'a');
insert into foo_blahs (foo_pk, blah_pk) values ('a_foo', 'b');
insert into foo_blahs (foo_pk, blah_pk) values ('a_foo', 'c');
```

and the delete query would become:

```
delete from blahs 
where not exists (select 1 from foo_blahs where foo_blahs.blah_pk = blahs.pk)
  and not exists (select 1 from bar where bar.blah = blahs.pk)
  and not exists (select 1 from baz where blahs.pk in (baz.a_blah, baz.another_blah));
```

Comment: Yeah, `foo`'s "foreign key" setup wasn't my idea -- but you do what you have to do to deal with data designed in flat-file-land...I'd rather have a many-to-many table myself but that creates special-casing problems in other places, sadly.

Comment: Ah well you do what you gotta do.  If you could do the many-to-many representation, you could add an errologging table to blahs `EXECUTE DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('blahs', 'errlog');` then you could simple `delete from blahs log errors into errlog ('doh') reject limit unlimited;` and the referential integrity will keep the referenced blahs from being deleted.  Make the errlog table a global temporary table and you won't even need to worry about cleaning it out periodically.

Comment: As to your first query -- the basic structure worked, but your WHERE clause turned out to be a massive generator of false positives.  I replaced it with an application of INSTR -- I don't think it's as performant as LIKE, but it at least returns a correct set of records.